# How does the gam library calculate AIC?

Tags: r, regression, nonparametric, aic, generalized-additive-model

I was wondering how the `gam` library calculates the AIC. I can't find a reference that explains how this package calculates it.

```
library("gam")
data(airquality)
model <- gam(Ozone^(1/3) ~ lo(Solar.R) + lo(Wind, Temp), 
             data=airquality, na=na.gam.replace)
model$aic
```

Comment: It looks like the `aic()` function called by `gam` is literally defined by the particular `family()` just as for GLM (`gaussian` by default); e.g. to actually see it for the `gaussian` case, type `gaussian` in R, for the gamma case, type `Gamma` and so on).  You can even get just the aic function with  `gaussian()$aic` (etc).
 However, it doesn't add the +2p at that point (that's added when calling it, so the same function will work for BIC, MDL and so on). As far as I can see the `gam` code just calls the `aic` function defined by the `family` code. The call to `aic()` is in `gam.fit`

Comment: The *gam* package implement AIC in the manner described in Hastie & Tibshirani's monograph on GAMs (IIRC). This is know to give poor results. Simon Wood and colleagues recently proposed a new way of computing an AIC which is implemented in the **mgcv** package but only for GAMs fitted with that package.  [Wood, S. N., Pya, N. & Säfken, B. Smoothing Parameter and Model Selection for General Smooth Models. J. Am. Stat. Assoc. 111, 1548–1563 (2016).](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/01621459.2016.1180986)

Comment: Would you want to answer this if it were reopened, @GavinSimpson? (Generally, questions about function f in software s are off topic here, but a discussion of the different AIC methods implemented "requires statistical expertise" & would be on topic.)

Comment: @gung right; I was thinking to maybe give the OP chance to respond/revise their Q, but I could also propose an edit and then prepare an answer. Won't happen today though as I'm travelling, but I think there are some useful statistical issues to raise with AIC and GAMs, and some new developments in Simon & co's paper plus the discussion to it.

Comment: Today is no big deal, @GavinSimpson, but if you're interested in doing that, I'll reopen.